# Black screen in start up after installing avast free edition in windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I am using windows 8 Pro x64. I did install Avast Free Edition a few days ago. After installing it my Windows is not starting rather it hangs on the welcome page providing a light black page. By pressing CLRL+ALT+DEL I can restart it. After one or two tries it opens up....What is the problem....

Comment: Does uninstalling Avast fix the problem? If not, it's probably not avast that caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by Avast not Windows 8. Avast is blocking the Windows Metro Apps.

After restarting the system get the task manager and open the file location by right clicking on the process.

Open Avast and go to the behavior shield and uncheck the **blocking unauthorized** option (may be 3rd option) and then restart your system .

This should solve the black screen problem.

If it does not, then uninstall Avast and check if it will work fine